# `console.log` a mobx `@observable` whenever its value changes

Tags: javascript, state, observable, mobx

Is there any way that a `console.log` will automatically fire whenever a mobx `@observable` changes value?

I would do it with mobx dev tools but it fires a huge amount of console logs so it's hard to pin point the property whose value I am tracking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
//store.js
import { autorun } from 'mobx';
autorun(() => {
  console.log(store.value); //value is an observable.
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [Reaction](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/reaction.html),
For logging you'll probably want to use autorun, but you should know there's another option, which
can gives you more control over when to run your callback.

I also like it because the syntax makes more sense:

```
import { reaction } from 'mobx'

class SomeStore {
    @observable item;
    @observable otherObservable;

    constructor() {
        reaction(
            // The callback will run only on change 
            // of observables described in this function
            () => this.item,
            // You can use whatever observables/computed values in this function
            // without making the function run on an unwanted observables change
            () => {
                if (this.otherObservable) {
                    doSometing();
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

There are more options to this function, you can read about it in the provided link.